# $this->render() function vs connect::router

Tags: php, cakephp

So, I'm not sure what to do here. Do I use render() to call a subview in or should I route() to the child controller of the view I want to display?

In the render() use it does not use the controller of the rendering (child) view as the variables are undefined. I used the ClassRegistry::init to get access to the function I need to retrieve the variables I need.

Though, when I use the Connect::router I am able to route to the controller of the child view through using the extend() function and the start()/end() without any need to get access to the child's model.

I understand the the render() only renders a view and doesn't access the model unless told. I just want to know the best way of calling a child view.

Comment: This sounds pretty messy. I doubt you're following the MVC pattern correctly. Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but my guess is that you're looking for Elements and getting it's variables automatically regardless of where they're used with requestAction() - [described here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element).

> You can take full advantage of elements by using requestAction(). The
>   requestAction() function fetches view variables from a controller
>   action and returns them as an array. This enables your elements to
>   perform in true MVC style. Create a controller action that prepares
>   the view variables for your elements, then call requestAction() inside
>   the second parameter of element() to feed the element the view
>   variables from your controller.